# Is data recovery possible in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: data-recovery

I am currently using Ubuntu 13.04 along with Windows XP SP3. A couple of days ago, Ubuntu crashed. Whenever I start the PC, the dual boot window appears, and when I select Ubuntu I get a black screen with a command line starting with `initramfs`. I cannot mount my Ubuntu.

How can I recover my data?

Comment: Have you tried googling about `initramfs`? It's just init in RAM, probably you screwed up something in the system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try TestDisk.

> TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily
>   designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks
>   bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software,
>   certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting
>   a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really
>   easy.

To install, visit the [Website](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download), or click [**TestDisk** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/testdisk/).

Also take a look at [Data Recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) it may be of help.

<sup>Source:TestDisk</sup>